# Why in editorwindow I don't see anymore the save/load buttons and there is no button to select prefab at the EditorGUI.ObjectField?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor, unity-editor

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveTransformsInfo : EditorWindow
{
    public GameObject source;

    [MenuItem("Tools/Save Transforms")]
    private static void CreateReplaceWithPrefab()
    {
        const int width = 340;
        const int height = 420;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        GetWindow<SaveTransformsInfo>().position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        //EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        source = (GameObject)EditorGUI.ObjectField( new Rect(10, 30, position.width - 1, 20),
            "Select Prefab", source, typeof(GameObject), true);
        //EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        if (Selection.transforms.Length > 0)
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Save Transforms"))
            {
                TransformSaver.SaveTransform(Selection.transforms);
            }

            if (GUILayout.Button("Load Transforms"))
            {
                TransformSaver.LoadTransform(true, source, false, "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot :

[image: Mess]

The save/load buttons not show.

The ObjectField the text description and the field too far from each other.

I can't select a prefab or a gameobject. There should be a small dot near the field pressing on it should open a window with all prefabs/gameobjects.

How can I organize all that ?

[image: Doors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There should be a small dot near the field

On the right edge of your picture you can still see the "dot" you are missing. It is simply too far on the right!

---

That is caused by you using `EditorGUI.ObjectField` with a fixed `Rect` for its position and size that simply doesn't fit into the window size. Mostly it is caused by

```
position.width - 1
```

this `- 1` gives you 1 pixel .. which is the 1 pixel of the dot you can see in your Screenshot. You **could** use

```
position.width - 10
```

so you can see the full dot. (I would then also recommend to not use `20` for the field height but rather `EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight`).

so like

```
source = (GameObject)EditorGUI.ObjectField(new Rect(10, 30, position.width - 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), "Select Prefab", source, typeof(GameObject), true);
```

However this will still behave strange once the width gets actually smaller then the x position of the field. Also note that you can't mix `EditorGUI` and `GUILayout` .. your buttons would be displayed on top of the `ObjectField`. So you would also need to use `GUI.Button` with accordingly calculated `Rect`s .. I wouldn't recommend it.

---

Instead you should rather simply use the [`EditorGUILayout`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.ObjectField.html) variant which uses the automatic Inspector Layout

```
source = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Select Prefab", source, typeof(GameObject), true);
```

[image]

[image]

---

> The ObjectField the text description and the field too far from each other.

The distance between the automatic label and the field could be changed by using [`EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility-labelWidth.html) and set a shorter width (you'll either have to calculate it or find the best one via trial and error) e.g.

```
EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 80;
source = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Select Prefab", source, typeof(GameObject), true);
```

[image]

Note however that this will apply to the entire EditorWindow not only that specific field because usually you want all your fields start aligned.

Or alternatively if you don't want to affect all fields you can do what apparently you tried already and use `BeginHorizontal` and `EndHorizontal` and move the label to a `LabelField` with fixed width

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Select Prefab", GUILayout.Width(80));
source = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(source, typeof(GameObject), true, GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

Note here, however, that this label is no longer "linked" to the field → it won't turn blue when the field is selected nor bold when it is changed.

---

Finally to

> The save/load buttons not show.

the code says

```
if (Selection.transforms.Length > 0)
```

so my guess is that you don't have anything selected **in the Scene**

see [`Selection.transforms`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection-transforms.html)

> Returns the top level selection, **excluding Prefabs**.
>
> This is the most common selection type when working with **Scene objects**.

once you have it should work just fine:

[image]